# Unexpected Result for Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

I am trying to cause an implicit type conversion between an `int` and `unsigned int` in some code that I wrote. The compiler gives an unexpected result.

According to the rules for implicit conversion between signed and unsigned integers (of equal rank), the code should produce a large positive number as its output.

```
unsigned int q = 90;
int w = -1;
printf("q+w=%u\n", q + w);
```

As the output to this program, which you can view [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ12uLhR4), the result is 89. I would expect the `int w` to be coerced to the type `unsigned int` before arithmetic occurs, however, and produce the expected result.

Comment: @user3121023 You're totally right. Assigning abs(w)-1 to `q` gives `UINT_MAX` now, as demonstrated [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJCCJvhAE).

Comment: @user3121023: Correct -- except that you can drop the "maybe".

Comment: Your compiler, with the appropriate warnings enabled ( for `gcc`, the appropriate  option is `-Wconversion` ) warns you that this implicit conversion can result in an incorrect result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` gets converted to `UINT_MAX` (the formal rule for converting to unsigneds is that you [repeatedly add or subtract the maximum+1 until the result fits (6.3.1.3p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2)). `UINT_MAX+90 == 89`.